# Why didn't Dany directly aim the Night King?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Why did she attack the White soldiers first? Had she attacked the night king immediately upon her arrival the entire walking dead would have been destroyed, isn't it? Any war tactics?

Comment: Because then the series would end this season. On a serious note, she has no idea who the Night's King is and that she should attack him.

Comment: She has only heard the words "Night's King" she has no idea what he looks like, or at that distance would be able to pick him out of a crowd. Take out the direct threat to your allies first.

Comment: Makes sense. Assuming that Cersei comes to her aid, what could be the next tactic?

Comment: Jon and friends only recently learned that killing the one who turned the others kills the turned as well. She doesn't have this information yet.

Comment: @Skooba to be fair she *did* see the Children's drawings in that cave on DragonStone.. NK was *somewhat* recognizable ;-) @ adityav she explicitly tells Jon she wants to kill the Night King (presumably to avenge Viserion), what more do you need?

Comment: How would she have attacked them? The White Walkers appear to be immune to fire.

Comment: They are not. Fire is what killed the White bear.

Comment: The _wight_ bear is not a White Walker, it is a reanimated bear. Wights seem to be susceptible to fire, but White Walkers can neutralise it with cold air (see Hardhome episode when the Walker appears in the townhall and kills the Thenn). The only way to kill White Walkers, as far as we know, is with Valyrian steel or dragonglass.